# Question about these filter or dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The problems: (dont mind the upper section)

- When I click a checkbox the result of the other checkbox also display and it also seems to be adding a margin at the bottom because the popup is moving down.
- Second I cant seem to find a way find a way to display the 2 sections side by side.
- Is there a way that I could make it that only one checkbox per section can be selected? And if the use changes their mind and click a different checkbox it will also change the displayed result.

heres the codepen link: 
https://codepen.io/racrdvz/pen/RwWZrog

```
<div class="pickerSection">
<section>
  <div class="watchingFor">
    <p class="type">Watching for:</p>
    <div class="menuToggle">
      <div class="menuToggleBtn"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Id2MrBQ.png" alt="" id="watchfor-btn" class="menuBtn">  </div>
      <div class="menuToggleBtn">
        <span class='display beginner'>30 days</span>
        <span class='display intermediate'>60 days</span>
        <span class='display advanced'>90 days</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

heres the look im going for:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Forgive me for the multiple questions, any help and suggestion will be much appriciated. Thanks

Comment: The easy option for "only one checkbox per section can be selected" is just to use [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead of checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

the solution to point 1 - use the different name of id and class for checkboxes 
the solution to point 2 - USe row and col classes to get them in the same row